# How do I iterate over an ndarray without using for/while loops?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

For two given 1-d arrays or lists I can calculate the squared Euclidean distance via the function

```
import numpy as np

def npdistance(x1, x2):

    return sum((np.array(x1)-np.array(x2))**2)
```

Now for a given vector v and 2d-array X I would like to find the shortest squared Euclidean distance of any vector contained in X to the vector u without iterating over the elements of X with for/while loops. My attempt is

```
def npnearest(u, X):
    L=npdistance(u,X)
    return min(L)
```

which does not give me what I want. For example

```
 npnearest(np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]]))
```

would give me 16 instead of 0. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of numpy, prefer `np.sum` and `np.min`, rather than Python buildins `sum` and `min`.

We can adapt `npdistance` for 2D numpy vectors:

```
def npdistance(x1, x2):
    return np.sum((np.array(x1)-np.array(x2))**2, axis=1)
```

Consider matrix `x2`:

```
x2 = np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]])
```

Matrix `x2` has two axes:

- zeroth is vector number: `x2[0]` is `np.array([1, 1, 1])` and `x2[1]` is `np.array([2, 3, 4])`,
- first axis is for vector dimension: `x2[1][1]` is `3` (second element of first vector).

We perform sum along `axis=1` to get distances *for each* vector.

- Without `np.sum` `axis=1` it would return scalar,
- Using buildin `sum` gives sum of all vectors (ala `axis=0`).

`npnearest` works correct in this case.

```
def npnearest(u, X):
    L=npdistance(u,X)
    return min(L)

npnearest(np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([[1,1,1],[2,3,4]]))
```

gives 0.

Comment: What is the relation between "first axis is for vector dimension" and x2[1][1] is 3?

Comment: It means that first axis is used to access scalar components of the vectors. When `x2[i] = [a_0, a_1, a_2]`, then `x2[i][0] = a_0`, ..., `x2[i][2] = a_2`.